# Конвертация JSON в CSV

Tags: python, json, list, csv, словари

```json
{
    "id": [
        0,
        1,
        2
    ],
    "full_url": [
        "https://melbet.ru/line/",
        "https://melbet.ru/line/",
        "https://melbet.ru/line/"
    ],
    "type_stake": [
        "line",
        "line",
        "line"
    ],
    "type_sport": [
        "Football",
        "Football",
        "Football"
    ],
    "name_liga": [
        "England. League Cup",
        "Spain Copa del Rey",
        "Spain Copa del Rey"
    ],
    "player_1": [
        "Chelsea",
        "Deportivo Linares",
        "Atletico Baleares"
    ],
    "player_2": [
        "Tottenham Hotspur",
        "Barcelona",
        "Celta"
    ],
    "P1": [
        1.96,
        8.4,
        4.34
    ],
    "X": [
        3.56,
        4.94,
        3.72
    ],
    "P2": [
        4.44,
        1.342,
        1.78
    ],
    "time_update": [
        "05-01-2022-20:31",
        "05-01-2022-20:31",
        "05-01-2022-20:31"
    ]
}
```

Выше приведен json, как на основе него создать csv

[image: csv должен быть такого вида]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего воспользоваться модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html:)

```
import json
import pandas as pd #   pip install pandas

# json_str = "{...}" # JSON

data = json.loads(json_str)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
```

---

для любителей однострочников:

```
pd.DataFrame(json.loads(json_str)).to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы его excel понимал?

Comment: @splash58, можно либо сразу сохранить в Excel файл: `df.to_excel("result.xlsx", index=False)` либо использовать разделитель в CSV, который понимает Excel: `df.to_csv("result.csv", sep=";", index=False)`

Comment: ага. а я подумал, что проблема с кавычками вокруг строк :) конечно, сразу в ексель правильнее - тут и флоаты в даты слетят при открывании. Это я из любопытства

Comment: Thanks .....      :)